# How to import and read vibration data file extension of "atfx" format?

Tags: python, bigdata

Vibration monitoring raw data was obtained in one folder containing one `atfx` files and 15 `dat` files. The file essentially contains data measurements taken at every 0.3125 milli seconds for 14 hours. At each discrete time interval three values are recorded from the sensors thus giving a data set with 161.28 million rows and four columns (time, Rx, Ry, Rz). All these data are split into 15 'dat' files with meta file information contained in the single 'atfx' file.

Is there any way to read these data into Python directly for further processing?